# Проверка значений через PHP в MySQL работают только цифры

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL таблица:
[image: Таблица]

Структура:
[image: Структура]

PHP код на проверку значений:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include_once 'conf.php';

if(isset($_POST['user_login_user'])) $login_user = $_POST['user_login_user'];

if(isset($login_user))  {

mysql_query("SELECT money FROM users WHERE login_user = ".$login_user."");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(("SELECT money FROM users WHERE login_user = ".$login_user.""))) {
echo $row['money'];
}
}
?>
```

Сама проблема:
По коду видно, что я пытаюсь найти ячейку "money" из таблицы "users", у которой есть индификатор "login_user". 
Проблема в том что в логине берется только цифры, допустим, я хочу найти "money" у индификатора "123abc" то мне ничего не выдает, но если найти по "123" то находит нужную мне ячейку "money".

Comment: 1. а пользователь с логином 123abc вообще существует?
2. `if(isset($_POST['user_login_user'])) $login_user = $_POST['user_login_user'];` и `if(isset($login_user))` выполняют одну и ту же операцию дважды

Comment: 1.Смотрите, если я создам 2 ячейки с логином:123 и 123abc, то при проверке "money", то есть того скрипта php с логином 123abc, то мне покажет "money" именно в аккаунте с логином 123.


 
2. `if(isset($_POST['user_login_user'])) $login_user = $_POST['user_login_user'];` это проверка на получение данных. `if(isset($login_user))` это проверка на то что в переменной вообще что то есть, ну или как то так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть, это проблемы с кодировкой. На приведённом Вами скриншоте видно, что у столбца login_user установлено сравнение, отличающееся от других столбцов. Попробуйте установить и для этого столбца utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Раньше было у обоих utf8_general_ci, но проблема была. Я просто проверял может из за кодировки не работают буквы.

Comment: В таком случае стоит задуматься о правильности функций для работы с БД и самих SQL-запросах. Прежде всего бросается в глаза повторение SQL-запроса. Вы передаёте его и функции mysql_query() и функции mysql_fetch_assoc(). Хотя по идее результат mysql_query() надо положить в переменную, а уже эту переменную передавать в mysql_fetch_assoc().

Comment: Ещё стоит подумать, во что превратится вот этот участок строки после подстановки значения переменной: login_user = ".$login_user."". Допустим, в $login_user лежит 123abc. Тогда получится строка: login_user = 123abc. Хотя по идее должно бы получиться: login_user = '123abc'.

Comment: Короче говоря, запрос надо изменить на "SELECT money FROM users WHERE login_user = '".$login_user."'".  По одинарным кавычкам MySQL поймёт, что значение атрибута - это строка.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сейчас проверю)

Comment: Спасибо большое, не думал что ошибусь в такой мелочи. Я вроде повысил вам "репутацию", наверно.